# Images in a responsive grid

Tags: html, css

I ran into a problem trying to create a grid menu, but instead of words in a grid square, I would like to add an image icon.

I've created the following grid:[image]

Below is the html and CSS I used:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  color: #444;
}

img {
  float: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

As shown on the picture above, adding an image with the picture does not get icon to sit in the grid box.

I don't know much of CSS.  Please assist.

Comment: I'd also add `display: block` to the `img` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in CSS ...

```
.box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    /* @VxP stated this: */
    display: block;
}
```

... for this HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

I created a fiddle to demonstrate this:

```css
.wrapper {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px;
grid-gap: 50px;

color: #444;
}

img {
    float:inherit;
    padding:10px;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

.box {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;

}

/* My code */


.box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    /* @VxP stated this: */
    display: block;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box a"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" /></div>
<div class="box b">B</div>
<div class="box c">C</div>
<div class="box d">D</div>
<div class="box e">E</div>
<div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

PS: Maybe you need `box-sizing: border-box` for this to work 100% correct. I added this to the above snippet.

Comment: how will I use this in HTML ? I tried <img class="box" ... but I dont get the desired result

Comment: Hi Paul, possibly there's something else I need to change because for some reason. when I add the div class="box" the icon image only moves slightly to the left but remain big and out of position

Comment: @kya I updated my answer. It works for me in latest Firefox, Windows 10.

Comment: I also added position: inherit in the .box img and that just makes sure that it stays in proper position

Answer (score 1):

The following css code for your image should be enough.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```